# Repeat specific columns of a tensor in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a pytorch tensor `X` of size `m x n`  and a list of nonnegative integers `num_repeats` of length `n` (assume sum(num_repeats)>0). Inside a forward() method, I want to create a tensor `X_dup` of size `m x sum(num_repeats)` where column `i` of `X` is repeated  `num_repeats[i]` times. The tensor `X_dup` is to be used downstream in the forward() method so the gradient needs to be backpropogated correctly.
All solutions I could come up with require inplace operations (creating a new tensor and populating it by iterating over  `num_repeats`), but if I understand correctly this won't preserve the gradient (please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm new to the whole Pytorch thing).

Comment: I will need to check more carefully in a bit but I believe [`torch.repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.repeat_interleave) might satisfy your needs (with `dim=1`)

Comment: @ jodag Precisely, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you're using PyTorch >= 1.1.0 you can use [`torch.repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.repeat_interleave).

```
repeat_tensor = torch.tensor(num_repeats).to(X.device, torch.int64)
X_dup = torch.repeat_interleave(X, repeat_tensor, dim=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. to(X) is to ensure X_dup is stored in the same device? Why is long() needed

Comment: Yeah, though actually `.to(X)` also converts the tensor to `X`'s dtype, we actually want the second argument for `repeat_interleave` to be a `torch.int64` type. While technically the original answer worked I edited it to avoid the unnecessary casting.